# $.ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 3 files:

**f1.php**

```
<?php
 echo 'dis';
?>
```

**f2.js**

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "scripts/f1.php",
  success: function (rsp){

   // if its not exist
   if(rsp == "dis"){
    $("#sbmt_a").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable Button
    //return = true;
   }
    else{
     $("#sbmt_a").removeAttr("disabled");
     // return = false;
    }
  }
 })
```

**p1.php**

```
//include f2.js - this is removed. code from f2.js is added at the bottom just before </body>
<body>
<form>
...
<button id="sbmt_a" name="sbmt_a" class="eee">Submit</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
  url: "scripts/f1.php",
  success: function (rsp){

   // if its not exist
   if(rsp == "dis"){
    $("#sbmt_a").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable Button
    //return = true;
   }
    else{
     $("#sbmt_a").removeAttr("disabled");
     // return = false;
    }
  }
 })
});
</body>
```

Now if I add in my js file something like `form.submit(function(){` I can use the `$.ajax` code and do whatever I like.

**But** is there a way to run the `$.ajax` code **when someone visits my page?** I mean when my page loads/reloads and the echo in f1.php is "dis" the form button becomes disabled.

Comment: @Downvoter, please care to comment as to why this question has been down-voted for the OP/other readers to understand why the down-vote and how the question could be improved upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put in your AJAX call within in the page `p1.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

In most cases, this event triggers as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed.

Comment: I tried this but as an external js file but it didn't work. Does it HAVE to be in my p1.php?

Comment: Yes, if you wish to trigger it the time when someone visits your page `p1.php`. To generalize the statement, you may put the call in any page that you wish should trigger the call when someones visits the same.

Comment: ok... Thank you. I didn't know know that. I though by including the file it was doing the check...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply run the ajax code when page finishes loading

```
$(function(){

$.ajax({
  url: "scripts/f1.php",
  success: function (rsp){

   // if its not exist
   if(rsp == "dis"){
    $("#sbmt_a").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable Button
    //return = true;
   }
    else{
     $("#sbmt_a").removeAttr("disabled");
     // return = false;
    }
  }
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the $.ajax call in your document.ready function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: "scripts/f1.php",
 success: function (rsp){

 // if its not exist
 if(rsp == "dis"){
  $("#sbmt_a").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //Disable Button
  //return = true;
 }
  else{
   $("#sbmt_a").removeAttr("disabled");
   // return = false;
  }
}
```

})
  });